# Is there a term for the direct opposite?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Suppose I have two words, let's take "true" and "false". "False", is the direct opposite of "truth", and is an antonym of "truth". However, the word I am looking for is not "antonym".

If I was to ask what was the "direct opposite" of "black", the answer would have been "white".
What word could have replaced "direct opposite" in this case?

Other examples include "dark" and "light", or "big" to "small". It is true these are antonyms, but these are special antonyms, they are the only ones that are the "equivalent opposites". 
"big" has other antonyms like "tiny", but "tiny" is the equivalent of "huge". "big"'s equivalent in opposite is "small".

EDIT, The word I am looking for has the meaning of "opposite *match*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try [antithesis](http://m.wordnik.com/words/antithesis)

> 1. Direct contrast; opposition.
> 2. The direct or exact opposite

Comment: +1, one can argue that it is always contextual, but the word does exist. kudos.

Comment: I agree that it works for true and false, but it sounds awfully strange to say "big is the antithesis of small."

Comment: @Kit now that you've written it, it looks strange; maybe "awfully" but I'm not yet sure ;)

Comment: @Third care to share how you've been using it lately? I'm just curious! :)

Comment: My question "Antithesis of International"

Comment: Antithesis is the opposite of a *thesis*. If the thing you're comparing against can't be characterised as a *thesis* (maybe metaphorically speaking), then *antithesis* probably isn't the right choice of word.

Comment: @slim of course! :) feel free to use another word then :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll find such a single word, apart from… ***antonym***.

*True* and *false* are antonyms, and so are *black* and *white* (listed as such in the *New Oxford American Dictionary* and other sources). You can look for synonyms of *antonym*, but the lists given (***opposite***, ***reverse***) do not include anything that seems relevant to what you search (so you're a bit unclear).

Comment: I told you I'm not looking for an antonym!

Comment: @Third Idiot: please give a better example; *white* is an antonym of *black*, so *antonym* really fits your question. In addition, the crux of my answer is that there is no single word term for this.

Comment: it seems pageman managed to find a single word

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic term is "diametric opposite." I don't believe there is a single word for this.

Comment: there is - it's antithesis - noun. A proposition that is the diametric opposite of some other proposition.

Comment: Ooh! Good word! It had completely slipped my mind!

Answer (score 1):

How about **inverse**?
As an adjective: Opposite or contrary in position, direction, order, or effect.
As a noun: Something that is the opposite or reverse of something else.

Answer (score 1):

*Converse* or *counterpart* if the context so requires.

Answer (score 0):

You tend to use direct opposite in terms of location

"His house is directly opposite mine"

Otherwise the word **opposite** by definition means what you're asking for.

Other words don't match in all cases such as `reverse` or `contrary`, opposite itself seems the universal one.

Answer (score 0):

In logic, you'd call it "contradiction". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition

Comment: You can't say, "What is the contradiction of "black"?" People wouldn't get you.

Comment: You could say it, just to be contrary. :P

Answer (score -1):

antipode or antipodal would suit this