# What is the term for exact matching antonyms

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for describing an exact matching pair of antonyms?  In the example below we have a pair of synonyms and antonyms.  However, I want to explain to my coworkers that when they name pairs of variables for actions they should use matching pairs, like the pair Start-Stop, and not to use other matches like Start-End.

Start - Stop

Begin - End

After asking this question I found a previous post that contained the same question: [Is there a term for the direct opposite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27314/is-there-a-term-for-the-direct-opposite)

Comment: I don't think they're the perfect examples. _Stop_ is not exactly equal to _end_. Something can have many _stops_ but only one _end_

Comment: "Antonym" is a very vague word. It's rare to find a case where everyone would agree that a pair of words are exact antonyms with no other antonyms being possible for either of them. For example, what is the exact antonym of "big": is it "small" or "little"?

Comment: I disagree with your example. 'Start' can pair with 'end' just as well as 'stop'

Comment: I was just trying to provide an example so that people had a better understanding of my question.  It sounds like there is not a single word that perfectly describes this as I originally thought.

Comment: These are the sorts of terms that drive programmers nuts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `polar opposite` comes to mind, but I don't think there is a precise term for what you're describing, because "exact matching pairs" don't exist as such (outside of e.g. maths and sciences). English is too much of a mushy, hand-wavey language.

The examples you give depend on context. For example--why not `start`/`finish`?

Besides that, splitting hairs over variable naming conventions...is not a great use of time ;)

Comment: Very true, it depends on the context to decide which pairs make sense.  I actually do think that naming in software is very important especially when english is a second or third language for our development team.  It makes the code very hard to read and to understand.

Answer (score 0):

How about "antithesis"? It seems to have a few different meanings, the simplest of which is:

- a person or thing that is the direct opposite of someone or something else.